# BizTalk SQL Adapter returns data but after I map it to another schema the transformation returns empty xml document

Tags: biztalk

Has anyone faced this issue before. I am trying to use the BizTalk SQL Adapter to read data from stored procedure using ( for xml auto, elements, xmldata ). the data is returned normally (I push it to physical file and the data is there) but after I map this returned data to a another schema (with similar structure), the file generated after the transform is always empty file. I want to know what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your map?

Comment: Are you using XSLT or the mapper? Make sure the root node namespace in your SQL adapter is setup to the correct namespace which is expected in your map.

Comment: thank you  Pieter I am using the mapper and the schema is auto generated with the same namespace that I specified. I added a root element to the generated schema and it worked I am not sure why it happened and why did this solve it

Comment: First, did you Test Map in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the schema with xmldata then after that replace it with root('rootName') then update the schema by adding a child element rootName and make it as a father element for the xml data  right after the auto generated root